# replace sql with where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know, that I can find info that I need through

```
SELECT * from x6fnckq9h_posts
where post_status = 'publish' and post_content like '%new.%'
```

ALso, I know that I can replace text in the field with

```
update TABLE_NAME 
set FIELD_NAME = 
       replace(FIELD_NAME, 'find this string', 'replace found string with this string');
```

What I need is: replace every `'%new.%'` with `''`

So, is it right to send

```
update x6fnckq9h_posts
  set post_content = replace(post_content, 'new.', '') 
WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_content like '%new.%';
```

Comment: you dont really need the `and post_content like '%new.%'` part

Comment: The LIKE part isn't that bad at all since it keeps transaction size down. (write set etc.) Keep it!

Comment: I don't see why it would not work.

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder just afraid to kill something :D , so decided to ask here)

Comment: I have done plenty of similar queries in the past without killing anyone :D

Comment: If you are worried, just create a duplicate of the table before running the query

Comment: @Arth good idea! THX

Answer (score 1):

If you're nervous, turn the update into a select and eyeball the output to see if it looks OK:

```
select
  post_content old_post_content,
  replace(post_content, 'new.', '') new_post_content
from x6fnckq9h_posts
where post_status = 'publish'
and post_content like '%new.%'
```

If you like the proposed changes, and as long as you use the exact same where clause, running your update will be OK.

Comment: looks strange to me. can you explain me why you call like [needed_table] [strangename], replace... , [anotherstrangename]?

I just don't get it %/

Comment: @ЛысенкоАлексей that syntax is a column *alias* - it renames the column of the returned rowset. I named them so it would clearly distinguish the two columns from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running update, just do a select with both fields.

```
SELECT post_content, replace(post_content, 'new.', '') 
FROM x6fnckq9h_posts
WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
  AND post_content like '%new.%';
```